# Condition for appending data into table

Tags: jquery

I'm using following script

```
function AddRowToTable(building, office, name) {
    $("#printerList").append("<tbody><tr>" + 
        "<td><p>" + building + "</p></td>" + 
        "<td><p>" + office + "</p></td>" + 
        "<td><a language='vbscript' onclick='AddP(&#39;\\\\dc8prt1.dc05.domain.net\\" + name + "&#39;)' href='#'>" + name + "</a></td>" +
        "</tr></tbody>");                                   
}
```

The third column is printer name where I'm adding script for mapping this printer.
It works fine, but I want also include condition:

If `name` contains `'891'`, then the `onclick` link should be `'AddP(&#39;\\\\dc8prt1...)'`. Otherwise the link should be `'AddP(&#39;\\\\dc9prt1...)'`

I hope I explained understandable.
Thanks.

Comment: So what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about value and onclick being A and B - it's really not clear at all.

Comment: Please be clear about your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but if I am right then you want a different URL depending on the name? If so, try something like this:

```
function AddRowToTable(building, office, name) {
  // Set the default (A).
  var url = "&#39;\\\\dc8prt1.dc05.domain.net\\" + name + "&#39;";

  // Check name and change url if required.
  if (name == "B")
    url = "&#39;\\\\something.different.domain.net\\" + name + "&#39;";

  $("#printerList").append("<tbody><tr>" +
    "<td><p>" + building + "</p></td>" +
    "<td><p>" + office + "</p></td>" +
    "<td><a language='vbscript' onclick='AddP(" + url + ")' href='#'>" + name + "</a></td>" +
    "</tr></tbody>");
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Following the question edit, if you want a 'contains' condition then you can use `indexOf`

```
if(name.indexOf('891') > -1)
    url = "&#39;\\\\dc9prt1.dc05.domain.net\\" + name + "&#39;";
```